# eps estimation for DBSCAN by not using the already suggested algorithm in the Original research paper

Tags: algorithm, dbscan

I have to implement DBSCAN using python, and the epsilon estimation has been posing problems as the already suggested method in the original research paper assumes blob like distribution of the dataset, where as in my case it is more of a cure fittable data with jumps at some intervals. The jumps cause the DBSCAN to form different clusters of various datasets in the intervals between jumps(which is good enough for me), but the epsilon calculation dynamically for different datasets does not produce desired results as the points tend to lie on a straight line for many intervals, and changing 'k' value cause a considerable change in the eps value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using OPTICS algorithm, you won't need to estimate eps in that.
Also, I would suggest recursive regression, where you use the python's best curve fit `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to get best curve, and then find the rms error of all the points wrt the curve. Then remove 'n' percent of points, and recursively repeat this untill your rms error is less than your threshold.

Comment: I have already started my work on OPTICS, but I neede to work with DBSCAN as well, because then I would be combining the output from both of them (and BIRCH) to get desired output (outliers)

Comment: Why do you wish to use multiple algorithms?

Comment: Because the shear skewdness of the datasets that I have to use would not make it possible for any of the present algorithms to do it single handedly. Therefore I would be using a probabilistic approach with each of the algorithms assigning the outlier probablity to the outliers and then the total probability would then be used to get a net weighed output, which when above a certian threshold would be classified as an outlier.

Comment: Godspeed dude, even implementing a single algorithm on your own would take a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Thanx mate, thouth recursive regression (i'm not sure if the terms exists) is a nice idea to be implemented as well