# How to determine the parameters of DBSCAN?

Tags: dbscan

I tried the kdist plot as introduced in one paper I read and used the knee distance to set the epsilon. However,the results were not satisfying.
I use the WEKA to implement DBSCAN, but it always returns only one cluster. 
Can anyone please give me some advice?

Comment: Be more specific about the outcome and desired outcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eps estimation for DBSCAN by not using the already suggested algorithm in the Original research paper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325591/eps-estimation-for-dbscan-by-not-using-the-already-suggested-algorithm-in-the-or)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the k-dist plot has more than 1 knee (this can happen when the dataset contains clusters having different density, and the outcome you have obtained arise when the high density clusters are nested inside the low density ones).

The solution is to search the next knee and re-apply the algorithm on the core points you already have found.